# In R how to select specific cell values/elements, perform calculations with them and display it in a specific format

Tags: r

I have a survey dataset (df) somewhat similar like the below, where there are set of questions starting from Q1_Grid. It has three columns which are Weight, Total & Unweighted Base:

```
 Weight     Total             Unweighted Base
Q1_Grid   Unweighted Base            10000
          Base                       10000
          A lot better [5]           1000
          A little better [4]        2000
          The same [3]               3000
          Not applicable             4000
          Don’t know                 5000
          Net: Better                9%
          Net: Worse                 12%
          Mean                       2.81
          Standard deviation         0.86
          Standard Error             -
```

From this dataset I am trying to write a CSV output file in the format below:

```
Q1_Grid     Unweighted Base      10000
            Base                 10000
            Net: Balance         3%
```

The output contains the Questions (Q1_Grid) & the first two elements of Total (Unweighted Base, Base) & the difference of "Net:Worse" & "Net:Better" in percentage.

I wrote the following code but it is not giving me the desired result.

```
target<-c("Net: Worse","Net: Better")
dfT2$Unweighted.Base<-as.numeric(dfT2$Unweighted.Base)
dfT2 %>%
  select("Weight","Total","Unweighted.Base")
  filter(Total %in% target)
  mutate(dfT2,"Net Balance", diff(Unweighted.Base))
```

List of packages/libraries I have used is:

```
-library(tidyverse)
-library(dplyr)
```

Please do you have any other easy way to get the desired output? I am relatively new to R and hence would appreciate any help from the community.

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format as well, like `dput()`. Please read the `r` tag description for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using spread and gather?

```
 dfT2 %>% 
        spread(Total,Unweighted.Base) %>% 
        select('Weight','Unweighted Base' , 'Net.Better' ,'Net.Worse') %>% 
        mutate(NetBalance = Net.Worse - Net.Better) %>%
        gather(Total, Unweighted, -(Weight))
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. I tried using the code and it gave me the following output with some errors.

Comment: +   spread(Total,Unweighted.Base)
Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (85, 86, 87, 88, 173), (175, 176), (4, 18, 32, 46, 60, 74, 92, 106, 120, 134, 148, 162), (6, 20, 34, 48, 62, 76, 94, 108, 122, 136, 150, 164), (3, 17, 31, 45, 59, 73, 91, 105, 119, 133, 147, 161), (7, 21, 35, 49, 63, 77, 95, 109, 123, 137, 151, 165), (2, 16, 30, 44, 58, 72, 90, 104, 118, 132, 146, 160), (9, 23, 37, 51, 65, 79, 97, 111, 125, 139, 153, 167), (12, 26, 40, 54, 68, 82, 100, 114, 128, 142, 156, 170), (10, 24, 38, 52, 66, 80, 98, 112, 126, 140, 154, 168), (11, 25, 39, 53, 67, 81, 99, 113, 127, 141, 15)

Comment: >   select('Weight','Unweighted Base', 'Net: Better', 'Net: Worse')
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character">   mutate(NetBalance = Net: Better - Net: Worse)
Error in mutate(NetBalance = Net:Better - Net:Worse) : 
  object 'Net' not found
>   gather(Total, Unweighted.Base, -(Weight))
Error in gather(Total, Unweighted.Base, -(Weight)) : 
  object 'Total' not found

Answer (score -1):

What if you get the `Net: Balance` row by directly subtracting:

```
balance <- dfT2[dfT2$Total == "Net: Worse", "Unweighted.Base"] - dfT2[dfT2$Total == "Net: Better", "Unweighted.Base"]
```

And then you can bind that on to the end of your filtered data frame:

```
dfT2 %>%
    select("Weight","Total","Unweighted.Base") %>%
    filter(Total %in% target) %>%
    rbind(c("", "Net: Balance", balance))
```

Comment: @Braun. Thank you very much. Your code actually worked, But I am not able to interpret the output.

Comment: Weight       Total Unweighted.Base
1         Net: Better              54
2          Net: Worse              14
3         Net: Better              67
4          Net: Worse              17
5         Net: Better              11
6          Net: Worse              35Net: Better              53
8          Net: Worse              56
9         Net: Better               9
10         Net: Worse              39
11        Net: Better              62

Comment: Net: Worse              16
13        Net: Better               1
14         Net: Worse               1
15        Net: Better               1
16         Net: Worse               1
17        Net: Better               1
18         Net: Worse               1
19        Net: Better               1
20         Net: Worse               1
21        Net: Better               1
22         Net: Worse               1
23        Net: Better               1
24         Net: Worse               1
25               <NA>             -40